# Does taking log affects units of original values

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

We know that  $\log (a) - \log (b) = \log {(a/b)}$, suppose if $a$ and $b$ are some values with units say metre, the operation $\log (a)-\log (b)$ results in $x$ output with units, but the$ \log {(a/b)}$ results in cancellation of units. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Don't you think that you have just argued that you cannot input something with a unit in a logarithm?

Comment: A more clear indication that one cannot have a logarithm of something with a unit is the Maclaurin series $\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{3}x^3\ldots$.

Comment: In that case, what you have is actually $\log\frac ab=\log\frac a{\text{m}}-\log\frac b{\text{m}}$.

Comment: @B.Pasternak don't see how your second example makes sense... $1-x$ is dimensionless

Comment: @B.Pasternak And regarding the first, I think we've really shown that $\log(x)$ where $x$ has units sometimes makes sense provided in the expression there's a $\log(y)$ added to it where $y$'s units cancel out $x$'s